# weight to fee computation

Tags: weight, weighttofee

We have changed the decimal places of our currency to 10e8 and trying to understand how to adjust the WeightToFeePolynomial. When reading the code I noticed that filling up a block can produce a range in fees and was flabbergasted.

Can you please explain why there is a range of fees for a full block?
[full_block_fee_correct() test](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/rococo/constants/src/lib.rs#L114)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the test you are referencing is that it is just a sanity check for the fee implied by the value of the constant `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT` in a Substrate chain. You can see how the range of the test varies depending on the use intended for the chain. This is the range for the test for [Polkadot relay chain](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/polkadot/constants/src/lib.rs#L114) for example, which is orders of magnitude larger than [Rococo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/rococo/constants/src/lib.rs#L114) or [Westend](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/westend/constants/src/lib.rs#L114) testnets.

Since the value of `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT` and the definition of the function `weightToFee` are critical for the correct functioning of a Substrate chain, it makes sense to check that the output of `weight_to_fee(&MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT)` is a "reasonable" value. But this test does not make any implication beyond this sanity check.

Answer (score 2):

That test in particular is just a sanity check. We cannot hard-code a specific value since these values change every time we re-run the benchmark for `ExtrinsicBaseWeight`. You can see it in the comment above:

```rust
pub struct WeightToFee;
impl WeightToFeePolynomial for WeightToFee {
    type Balance = Balance;
    fn polynomial() -> WeightToFeeCoefficients<Self::Balance> {
        // in Rococo, extrinsic base weight (smallest non-zero weight) is mapped to 1/10 CENT:
        let p = super::currency::CENTS;
        let q = 10 * Balance::from(ExtrinsicBaseWeight::get().ref_time());
        smallvec![WeightToFeeCoefficient {
            degree: 1,
            negative: false,
            coeff_frac: Perbill::from_rational(p % q, q),
            coeff_integer: p / q,
        }]
    }
}
```

There needs to be some leeway for the production process, since otherwise these tests would fail on every release.